# Is it possible to publish an app based on a board game?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, board-game

Usually the boxes says "all rights reserved" and "registered trademark". What does it mean? Could others make an app with the game's name and mechanic? Is it possible to sell it, put banner ads or make it free?

Comment: For board games in particular, it depends on the game. Certain games like chess are in the public domain (although specific implementations with particular art probably art). Things like Monopoly, not so much. You should consult a lawyer.